# How Can I implement this API End point for Search Purpose Using React Query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, filtering, react-query

```
const { isLoading, isError, data, error, refetch } = useQuery(
    "university",
    async () => {
        const { data } = await axios(
            "http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?name=middle"
        );
        console.log("THis is data", data);
        return data;
        
    }
);
```

**And This is the Search Box Where I want to map Data of University name that is typed**

```
<Typeahead
            id="basic-example"
            onChange={setSelected}
            options={university}
            placeholder="Choose a School..."
            selected={selected}
        />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been asked so many times that I've added it to my react-query FAQs: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-fa-qs#how-can-i-pass-parameters-to-refetch

`searchValue` needs to be part of the queryKey:

```
const { isLoading, isError, data, error, refetch } = useQuery(
    ["university", searchValue],
    async () => {
        const { data } = await axios(
            `http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?name=${searchValue}`
        );
        console.log("THis is data", data);
        return data;
        
    },
);
```

then, once the user selects a new searchValue, the query will automatically refetch. If searchValue changes on every key stroke, use something like [useDebounce](https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/) to defer the query:

```
const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('') // value from search input

const name = useDebounce(searchValue, 500)

const { isLoading, isError, data, error, refetch } = useQuery(
    ["university", name],
    async () => {
        const { data } = await axios(
            `http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?name=${name}`
        );
        console.log("THis is data", data);
        return data;

    },
);
```

---

Comment: And if you want to move the axios part to a seperate file, what would be the approach then?

Comment: if the axios part lives in a different file that exports a function called `fetchUniversities` that takes a name as input, you just invoke that instead of calling axios directly?

Comment: Yeah that is what i do, but in this case you add the input to the first argument of the useQuery, so I was wondering how you would pass then, like `useQuery(["university", name], fetchUniversities(name))`;

Answer (score -1):

I think you can write something like this:

```
const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('') // value from search input


const { isLoading, isError, data, error, refetch } = useQuery(
    ["university", searchValue],
    async () => {
        const { data } = await axios(
            `http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?name=${searchValue}`
        );
        console.log("THis is data", data);
        return data;
        
    },
    false // you can disable automatic run (when empty)
);

useEffect(() => {
  refetch() // wrap with debounce function to not call on every change
}, [searchValue])
```

Comment: cannot render any data from it. i need to extract universities name from the api that autocomplete when we type something

Comment: @WajidAli what you mean you cannot extract data? What you get in `isLoading`, `isError`, `data`, `error ` properties?

Comment: Brother I want to extract only Universities from the API and apply filter on it, like if i type Abc It shows the list of ABC universities

Comment: @WajidAli StackOverflow is **not** a free code-writing service. If you need people to give you a complete program that runs and does what you do than hire a professional and pay them. Here we only help and educate, but this starts with you describing your attempts, what's wrong etc. Can you update your question by adding what you did to apply Buggies answer and describe why this is not working for you?

Comment: @GACy20 what Buggies tried I already did that passing it to useEffect so each time value update, I am not able to build logic right now that is the reason i asked for the help